# Where Can I Find a Single Right Front Crank Arm for a Tandem?

Tags: parts, tandems

Among the bikes in my stable is a department store tandem that really isn't worth much, but would be enjoyable to ride with my wife.  Like many department store bikes this one was not assembled correctly and now the pedal threads on the right front crank are beyond stripped, there are millimeters of smooth clearance around where it would screw in. It doesn't appear that it could be re-threaded.

The problem is, on a normal bike the right crank has the splines for the chainrings, and the left is unadorned.  On the front crank of a tandem this is backwards.  So while I can find replacement left crank arms, what I really need is a plain 170 mm right crank arm.

I've searched my usual online retailers to no avail - and don't want to spent the $$$ for a full, 4 crank arm tandem set.

Anyone know where I might find one?

Comment: Worst case you could use a left crank and rely on threadlocking compound to stop recession unscrewing the pedal : 
http://www.bikexprt.com/bicycle/tancrank.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that some BMXs have left side drive. I actually found this out by accidentally ordering a left hand freewheel that was backwards on my single speed!

I don't know if these cranks will work for you but it might be a place to look. Wikipedia describes left side drive [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_hub#BMX.2FSingle_Speed_Bicycles) .

[JensonUSA](http://www.jensonusa.com/store/product/CR407Z20-Sugino+Xd500+Tandem+Crank+Arm.aspx) have Sugino tandem crank arms sold separately.

Comment: Searching for Sugino Tandem Crank Arms and similar eventually let me to http://www.precisiontandems.com/ - they had single arms but JensonUSA had a better deal.

Answer (score 1):

The cheap options are fitting a [helicoil](http://www.emhart.com/brands/heli-coil/) or equivalent to replace the thread, or finding another cheap tandem that's been wrecked and get the part from that. The helicoil is probably the easiest option, but if you can find a wrecked tandem that will possibly be cheaper.

There are companies that re-tap cranks for tandems ([Greenspeed](http://greenspeed.com.au) is one) but that adds $50 or so to the cost, however it may be less because they have a surplus of spider-less cranks (a tandem needs three spiders and one spiderless crank, leaving two spare). It would be worth asking them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice bargain priced set on ebay right now - Sugino, search 'tandem crank' should get you there. Get your bid in, sure the crank will be good and you will have spares for all the rest. Failing that you can get a spare from Middleburn in the UK - pop them an email.